# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un cuadro con mensaje oculto con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Estoy haciendo un cuadro modal que se mostrará cuando una condición no se cumpla pero no estoy seguro como hacer la llamada con ***JavaScript***:

Éste es el modal:

```
  <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <h2>Error en Campos</h2>
      <p>Favor de verificar sus datos</p>
      <p>Algun dato puede estar faltante</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

y este es el JavaScript que debe mostrarlo:

```
if (valiName.checkValidity() || valiEmail.checkValidity() || valiIssue.checkValidity() || valiComment.checkValidity() ||
        valiDeparment.checkValidity() == false) {
        // alert("Favor de verificar los campos son llenados correctamente")
        document.getElementById("#openModal").display();
      }
```

Pero este *script* no hace nada. Estaré agradecido si pudieran ayudarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error con tu código.

La línea:

```
document.getElementById("#openModal").display();
```

debería ser:

```
document.getElementById( "openModal" ).style.display = "block";
```

Más detalles:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp

Y un ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>JS - Ver modal</title>
 
 <!--/
  @utor: Moisés Alcocer
  @web: https://www.ironwoods.es
 /-->

 <style>
  
  .btn {
   background: lightgrey;
   border: 1px solid black;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 5%;
   padding: 20px 50px;
  }
  .modalDialog { 
   background: lightgreen;
   display: none 
  }

  .btn,
  .modalDialog {
   margin: 5%;
   padding: 20px 50px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
   <p class="btn" onclick="cx()">Cerrar</p>
   <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, minima eligendi dignissimos quasi, natus veniam. Numquam dicta beatae possimus, praesentium optio inventore quidem deserunt reprehenderit voluptatum, ullam velit dolores, similique.</p>
  </div>
 </div>

 <p  id="showBtn" class="btn" onclick="sx()">Ver modal</p>

</body>
</html>
<script>
 
 function sx() {
  console.log( "Ver modal" );

  document.getElementById( "openModal" ).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById( "showBtn" ).style.display = "none";
 }
 function cx() {
  console.log( "Ocultar modal" );

  document.getElementById( "openModal" ).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById( "showBtn" ).style.display = "block";
 }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que la lógica me párese que esta invertida ya que el método `checkValidity` retorna `true` cuando cumple las reglas, ademas solo en el caso que el `validDeparment.checkValidity()` retorne `false`  mostraría el `modal`

```
if (!valiName.checkValidity() || !valiEmail.checkValidity() || 
    !valiIssue.checkValidity() || !valiComment.checkValidity() ||
    !valiDeparment.checkValidity()) {
       // alert("Favor de verificar los campos son llenados correctamente")
       document.getElementById("#openModal").display();
  }
```